# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Illegal invocation

Tags: typescript, rush

I have an object **host** in a typescript code, which is created as:

```
const host: Host = {
    fetch: globalThis.fetch,
    ...
}
```

Now when the entire project is built and ran on google chrome (using rush), then the system crashes and the console shows the error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Illegal invocation

This Error is caught on a statement that goes like

```
const response: Response = await host.fetch(url, ...);
```

I am unable to understand what does this error mean and what might have caused it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Seems like chrome does not let you call the fetch function using a reference to `global.fetch`. You have to use the `fetch` global function directly. Shame because I want to use injection tokens for easier unit testing.